# how to parse an XML document of unknown schema?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file, I don't know how the XML document is organized. How can I parse the XML in C#?

I tried this:

```
try
{                          
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmldoc);

    foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Attribute("").Value);
        Console.WriteLine("testing");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But without knowing the names of the nodes, I can't parse it.  How do I parse XML documents in C#?

Comment: And what do you want to do with xml?

Comment: If you are wanting to know how to parse xml dynamically (without knowing it's contents) it can be done with the expando object. Take a look here:http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/07/parse-xml-to-dynamic-object-in-c.html That said that solution only works depending on what you are wanting to do with the parsed xml...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I need to store these nodes in sql server database.

Comment: Link does not work [link] http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/07/parse-xml-to-dynamic-object-in-c.html

Comment: How do you need to store them? SQL Server has an "XML" data type that allows you to store an entire XML document, regardless of the schema.

Comment: For handling documents with unknown schema (and probably those with known schema as well) using XPath or XQuery invoked from your C# is the most flexible solution.

Comment: I am using the XML data type and storing the whole XML document. I want to create column for each node dynamically how can this be done